# Efficient way to communicate the changes made from licensing server to server in user's cloud

Tags: php, web-services, rest, amazon-web-services

What is the best way to communicate with the server (running in user's private cloud) for any change made to the database of licensing server(running in my own cloud)?

Scenario:

Licensing server or the authentication server operates on my cloud but its client operates on the private cloud of the user.  Now for any change made to the licensing server, what is the effective way for the server in private cloud to know the changes made? The change could be frequent or infrequent.

Possible solutions:

- The server in private cloud constantly pings the authenticating server for any changes made. But this might cause unnecessary engagement of the authenticating server. We could also implement this using socket programming, but given it is a private cloud, user might not allow opening the required port.
- The authenticating server communicates with the user's server on the private cloud. But I would never want the authenticating server to behave as a client. So, this should never happen.

Answer (score 0):

The licensing server will never be able to reliably reach out to a user's server due to network and security configuration. The user's server will have to periodically phone home to the licensing server to be notified of changes. In my experience, an application will typically only validate the license once every 30 days (or more). If your application needs to check more often then I suggest you have a method of allowing the server's user to manually trigger a phone home to the licensing server.